# UpgradeSchema/InstallData files not working

Tags: magento2, module, database, installation, upgradeschema

I've the following setup:

Company/Custom/etc/module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Custom" setup_version="1.0.6"></module>
</config>
```

Company/Custom/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php:

```
<?php

namespace Company\Custom\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{   
    $installer = $setup;

    $installer->startSetup();

    $eavTable = $installer->getTable('customer_entity');

    $columns = [
        'custom' => [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            'length' => '1',
            'nullable' => true,
            'comment' => 11,
        ],
    ];

    $connection = $installer->getConnection();
    foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
        $connection->addColumn($eavTable, $name, $definition);
    }

    $installer->endSetup();
}
```

}

I've removed the module from the `setup_module` table and run the upgrade commands.
Also, the module is appears in the dashboard and its enabled.

The problem is that table is not created in database after I run the scripts but if I put errors in the php file, the upgrade scripts run without error.

As you can see I incremented the module version in the `module.xml`.

Thanks.

Comment: You've put your code in upgrade schema, put your code into install schema to make it work

Comment: Please look at Magento\Cms\Setup\InstallSchema and do the same. And you forget about $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

Answer (score 1):

Your file name is `UpgradeSchema.php` but you have used the `InstallSchema` code. Change your file name to `InstallSchema.php` and code should be like this:

```
namespace Company\Custom\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();


        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Yes if you want to make change in Existing table then it should be in `UpgradeSchema` file. But main function name should be `upgrade` instead of `install` like below code:

```
namespace Company\Custom\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I was not getting any errors and nothing has happened. I was using the same code as well. I tried the solution above and more suggestions in other post and nothing fixed my issue.

I realized that my Setup folder was one level "above" the expected level.

**Expected directory level**

```
-Mastering->
--SampleModule->
---Setup->
```

**I had my "Setup" folder at the same level as my module.**

```
-Mastering->
--SampleModule->
--Setup->
```

I moved my "Setup" folder to the right level and everything worked as a charm!